# Preferred access method for Oracle 11g using .Net 4

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework-4, oracle11g

I need to develop an ASP.Net web application accessing and Oracle 11g database. What would be the preferred method / framework to access the DB?

At the moment I am using most of the time EF 4.x to access a SQLServer 2008 but it is a while ago I accessed Oracle.

THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

You can try [ODP.net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) which is Oracle's solution to connect .net apps to Oracle.

The latest version even has support for EF but it's probably not as complete as what you had with SQLServer.

And as your are developing an ASP.net app, it also ships with a membership provider.

Comment: The part that it is not complete is my fear... Does anybody has some experience how complete it is?